# A model that predicts the universe is finite in space and time

Tags: spacetime, universe, popular-science

A physics professor talked in the YouTube video [Cosmological Constant & The End of the Universe - Sixty Symbols](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHqkl51KzmM) about a paper he and his colleagues published. The paper presents a model that ties the mass of particles to the size of the universe. He summarizes their conclusion as: an infinite universe (in either time or space) would result in particles having zero mass, but particles do have mass so the universe must be finite in all dimensions.

I haven't even tried reading the paper; I'm not a physicist so I stand no chance of understanding it even vaguely, but I find the hypothesis interesting nonetheless.

Has anyone here read the papers? In layman's terms, what assumptions is their model based on and how likely is it that they are true?

Here are Arxiv links to the two articles:

- [Sequestering the Standard Model Vacuum Energy](http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1309.6562)
- [Vacuum Energy Sequestering: The Framework and Its Cosmological Consequences](http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1406.0711)

Comment: why does the link say it connects to youtu.be and not youtube.com? Also, consider posting the link to the actual paper and not a random video. But as it is, this is likely to be closed as non-mainstream physics

Comment: @Jim (a) youtu.be is the domain used by Google for short links to youtube.com videos. To convince yourself click on "Share" under any video. (b) I'll post links to the papers right now.

Comment: Just curious. No need to convince me. Thought you might have been using a Belarus domain or something, was going to point out that most people here prefer english

Comment: @Jim Oh, okay. I thought you were worried I posted a link to some phishing or malware site.

Comment: They say that the universe has finite *spacetime* which, it seems, they mean that it will *end* and not continue forever.

Comment: @KyleKanos that or they mean the penrose diagrams are unnecessary because there are no infinities. That seems kind of petty to base a paper on though.

Comment: @KyleKanos That's also what I got from it. I'm curious about the assumptions they make and how reasonable they are.